# Automatic video selector from galary android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-intent, upload

i am using this code for selecting the video from gallery app but the problem is that this will open the gallery app and user select the video manually i dont want that.I am looking for the code that will automatically pick video from gallery app by just giving the video path.. I just want to upload a specific video by giving video path from mobile storage to firebase

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
```

Comment: If you have the path already you dont have to let the user pick something. You can directly start the upload. I do not understand your problem

Comment: i have the video path.. please tell me how to gave the video path to firebase for upload

Comment: Since you say you already have the path, show us the code that uploads the file. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo please check the code below

Answer (score 0):

this code basically allow user to pick video from mobile storage and it is working fine.. but i want to automatically upload first video to firebase from folder Movies/CamerX-Videos. This folder is in my mobile storage

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val VIDEO : Int = 3
lateinit var uri : Uri
lateinit var mStorage : StorageReference
//val uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(File("/Internal storage/Movies/cameraX-Video/Has.mp4"))
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Uploads")
    val videoBtn = findViewById<View>(R.id.videoBtn) as Button
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Uploads")


    videoBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "video/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), VIDEO)


    })





}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    val uriTxt = findViewById<View>(R.id.uriTxt) as TextView
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == VIDEO) {
            uri = data!!.data!!
            uriTxt.text = uri.toString()
            upload ()
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
private fun upload() {


    var mReference = uri.lastPathSegment?.let { mStorage.child(it) }
    try {
        mReference?.putFile(uri)?.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot? -> var url = taskSnapshot!!
            val dwnTxt = findViewById<View>(R.id.dwnTxt) as TextView
            dwnTxt.text = url.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Uploaded :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

}